# Rain shelter for tablesaw

Tags: framing, roof, shelter

I'd like to build some kind of simple shelter on my uncovered deck so that I can use my tablesaw outside when it is raining.

I was hoping for something simple that I could make from 2x4s, rope, tarp and maybe bungie cords.  Ideally I'd also be able to put it up and take it apart within an hour (once I have it built).

Anyone build something like this, I don't have any ability to anchor things into the deck other than I could sandwich a couple 2x4s on the inside and outside of the aluminum rails so they could be secured as uprights.  My base idea would be 4 of these serving as posts and then get a tarp rigged between them at the 4 corners.  Maybe put each of the 4 tarp corner grommets on a rope and an eye bolt in each ~post to pull the tarp into position?  Probably make the two posts closest to the non house side of the deck shorter so the tarp sheds water in that direction.

The deck is probably 20' wide x 16' deep.

I've never put anything like this together...  so I am open to any thoughts / ideas.  I could get one of the those farmer market shelters but somehow that feels like cheating and with the weather always being rain it would get covered in dust and mold so something that lasts a year and I can build from scrap I think is nicer.

Comment: The four posts need to be attached to each other to prevent them from falling over and whacking you on the head.  For fast taking down would have front and back attached solidly, but sides with only pivots points(single screw/bolt).  Will need knee braces to keep stable(screw on/off).  When finished just need to undo knee braces and fold up.  Round and smooth top ends to give tarp some protection or use old inner tubes or similar stuff.

Answer (score 4):

If by "farmer market shelter" you're referring to a little pop-up tent:

[image: pop up tent]
<sup>Image from Harbor Freight. An example, not a recommendation</sup>

I'd think that would be the easiest thing to do. You could screw the feet down to the deck, or (if you don't want to damage the surface) simply slide some barbell-style weights (the kind they sell expressly for this purpose) around the feet. I've seen folk fill gallon milk jugs with water and rope them on to keep these from moving.

It's not going to get any more dust or mold covered than anything you build yourself. Actually, with much smaller legs than a home-built 2x4 based shelter, it will accumulate less, simply because there's less surface area. If it does, it's easy to hose off and/or wipe down with some bleach or vinegar to kill any mold. The metal legs would be easy to drill & tap to hang tarps around the legs to protect the saw from the weather (and prying eyes) while you're not using it.

I get that this isn't the DIY answer, but sometimes, the easy (and cheaper - have you noted lumber prices these days?) way is the right one. Spend the time and money on the projects that matter.

To be honest, if the "weather is always rain" to the point that you're worried about mold growing on your shelter, I'd be *far* more concerned about rust, potential mold growth, and dust caking into immovability on the saw than on the shelter. Frankly, you could buy 10 or more shelters for the price of one reasonable table saw, and protecting the saw would be a *much* higher priority to me than worrying about the tent over it.

Pro Tip™: watch your lumber storage. If you're storing & assembling outside in high humidity, then moving things inside to climate controlled lower humidity, you're going to have huge shrinkage issues as the wood dries out.

Comment: I just have a low range tablesaw.  It has wheels so I'd keep that inside and just wheel it out when I want to cut.   Just tired of the dust.  I likely have enough scrap that I can scab together the posts for free and I'd just to buy a tarp.  I tried one of these shelters and it didn't even last a season, water/snow accumulated and the center pole pushed through a seam in the canvas.